# Using fio with cognito session token

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cognito

I'm trying to access a AWS S3 buckets using the fio (flexible IO  tester) tool on linux but from the documentation it looks like the tool doesn't support session token from AWS Cognito service for authentication. Am I right ?

I tried to create a job file an include only the session key and session key ID